# Setting plain text email's body format to HTML using Microsoft Outlook Interop Library corrupts the email content

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-redemption

This seems to start happening out of no where since May this year to the desktop version of Outlook, almost looks like a bug from some recent update that Microsoft is rolling out.

So I have the following simple code to reproduce this problem:

```
var app = new Application();
var session = app.Session;
var mail = (MailItem)session.GetItemFromID("0000");

// mail.BodyFormat is olBodyFormat.Plain
// setting it to olFormatHTML corrupts the email body

mail.BodyFormat = OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;

// after setting the body format to olFormatHTML, the body format remains olBodyFormat.Plain
```

The email body text after trying to set the body format to HTML changes to incorrect Unicode characters.

The following code achieves the same result:

```
var app = new Application();
var session = app.Session;
var mail = (MailItem)session.GetItemFromID("00000");
mail.HTMLBody = mail.Body;
```

If the plain text body was "asdf" and the email body encoding is Western European (Windows), i.e. `InternetCodepage = 20127`, it converts the text to "獡晤".

At first I thought this could be a page encoding problem so I tried the following code:

```
var app = new Application();
var session = app.Session;
var mail = (MailItem)session.GetItemFromID("00000");
mail.InternetCodepage = 65001; // sets the email encoding to UTF-8
mail.HTMLBody = mail.Body;
```

Yet the same thing still happens.

It seems that if I use Redemption to do this, the problem doesn't happen, but there are side effects to do this with Redemption.

After Redemption updates the email body, the Outlook inspector or the email window doesn't change the body format, as if Outlook still caches the old value. If you reply this email now, the sent email will have an empty body.

Does any one know if I'm doing anything wrong here or this is really a Microsoft Outlook bug?

Comment: Do you get the same issue with a newly created messages in Outlook, not existing ones?

Comment: This doesn't happen to a newly created message. Although newly created messages using the interop lib has `InternetCodepage = 1252` but trying to set this to an existing plain text message doesn't help.

Comment: Does this only happen if you set `HTMBody` to `Body`? Does it happen if you set `HTMBody`  to a well-formed HTML string?

Comment: It happens as soon as you change the body format from plain text to HTML in any way, so setting anything to `HTMLBody` regardless if it's well formed HTML or not triggers the body type change and the corruption happpens.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a product issue. I'd recommend opening a support case with MS then.

As a possible workaround you can use the Word editor for setting up the message body correctly. The [Inspector.WordEditor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.wordeditor) property returns the Microsoft Word Document Object Model of the message being displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround Eugene. Unfortunately we have a lot of cases of getting the mail item just by entry ID regardless if they are visible or not so most of the times their inspector wouldn't be available.

Comment: You can use the `GetInspector` method at any point. It is not necessary the inspector window should be visible.

Comment: Awesome Eugene. I managed to get the Document object from the plain text email. 

However, when I try to execute `inspector.WordEditor.Range.InsertAfter("test")`, it gives me a `This method or property is not available because the document is locked for editing` error.

Some research pointed me to call the `document.Unprotect()` method so I tried that too, but calling that gives me `This command is not available` error. I guess this might be the email being a received email so the body is not editable in the Word editor, although `document.ReadOnly` gives me `false`.

Comment: Have you tried using raw Copy and Paste commands instead?

Comment: Anyway, that is another question. Don't forget to mark the answer.